# What is the name of a type of sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

"Who is he" is called an inquisitive sentence. I wonder what is the name of a sentence like "please close the door".

Comment: Except when repeating "him" for clarification, "Who is him?" is ungrammatical. It should be "Who is he?", an **interrogative** sentence. "Please close the door" is an **imperative** sentence, here used as a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences can be:

- Statements (declarative): John closes the door. (Subject-Verb order)
- Questions (interrogative): Is the door closed? (Verb-Subject order)
- Commands (imperative): [Please] close the door (Subject implied)

[This](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/type.htm) lists a fourth type, *exclamative* which would cover things like "What a X!" (Verb implied)